# How to make 3 row full scene how UITableViewCell occupy the complete screen?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am loading cell from nib (xib) tableviewcell

```
//tabelview cell register 

let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "ItemTableViewCell", bundle: nil) 

tableViewItemList.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ItemTableViewCell")
```

I have spent of very long time to solve this problem but I could not find any solution.

I need to show 3 rows of tableView and those three rows must occupy my screen. Currently, it is showing three rows but there is some extra white space remaining which I want to occupy by those rows.

[image: 1]

above is the screen I obtained. below is the design that I want to achieve.

[image: 2]

Comment: Please put a little more effort into your question. It's very hard to understand your goal and your problem.

Comment: You will have to find out the size (bounds) of the table view at run time (as it will be different for different size devices) and then you will have to set the height of the table view cells accordingly.

Comment: use estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath, heightForRowAtIndexPath method of UITableViewDelegate,
return tableView.frame.height/3 on both methods.

Comment: @Dari it should be my answers. thanks . where everyone down me

Comment: @cristanlika: user more proper english and ask question clearly. Its hard to understand what you asked.

Comment: @Dari could you edit that and provide your answer both i will accept if i alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following functions of UITableViewDelegate:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.frame.height/3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.frame.height/3
}
```

Comment: when i add navigation third number row out of screen. little bit . can you help me please what should i do ?